# Git/Github: Replace a submodule of a forked repository

Tags: git, github, saleor

### What I want

I have an [open source parent repository](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-platform) which I want to make a fork to work with it, this repository is composed of 3 submodules and some configuration files. What I want is to replace one of the submodules(`saleor-storefront`) with my own implementation(private repository) and I want to be able to update the other submodules and files with the changes made by the upstream repository.

Should I just change the path of the module I want to replace from the `.gitmodules` file or are there other changes involved that I'm not aware of?

#### Forked Project structure

```sh
saleor-platform
├── ./.gitmodules
├── ./common.env
├── ./docker-compose.yml
├── ./saleor
├── ./saleor-dashboard
└── ./saleor-storefront  -> Submodule to be replaced with my own implementation
```

### .gitmodules

```sh
[submodule "saleor"]
    path = saleor
    url = https://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git
[submodule "saleor-storefront"]
    path = saleor-storefront
    url = https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront.git
[submodule "saleor-dashboard"]
    path = saleor-dashboard
    url = https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-dashboard.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Git 2.25 command `git submodule set-url`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/6309) should help in order to update/replace the URL of one of your submodule by the one of your fork:

```
git submodule set-url -- saleor-storefront https://github.com/<me>/saleor-storefront
```

That way, you won't miss any "other changes" involved when modifying the URL of a submodule.