# Best way to learn to use GitHub

Tags: git, github, duplicates, git-fork

I've been trying to learn how to use GitHub but I just can't get a grasp on it.

One thing I want to do is, make a private fork from a public repo. For some reason the button to make a fork private is gone so now I have to 'duplicate' it.

Read some stuff hear and there and ended up using

```
git remote add upstream
git fetch upstream 
git rebase upstream/master
```

Commands were succesful, but I didn't notice a change, my duplicate didn't add the latest commits from the public repo.

I'm a little frustrated. I find GitHub incredibly hard to get grasp on.

I hope someone can ELI5 how I can update a duplicate of a repo, to the latest version of that repo. And explain it in detail so I learn what's it all about. I've been unsuccesful googling this.

Comment: I think this previous post may help you. You can no longer fork a public repo but you can duplicate it, which it sounds like you've done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065526/github-how-to-make-a-fork-of-public-repository-private

Comment: http://try.github.com/ has some nice tutorials for using git.

Comment: What would be the most straightforward way to update a duplicate to the upstream repo? Everyone keeps throwing tons of information at me but I just first just want to know this single thing.

Answer (score 0):

To get a good grasp of git you have to first understand the concept of distributed repository. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control

This link has some basic commands on git.

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Some of my fav git commands

clone a remote repository

```
git clone https://xxxxx.git
```

update code

```
git pull
```

create a branch from master

```
git branch new-branch
```

checkout to the newly created branch

```
git checkout new-branch
```

status

```
git status
```

add new files

```
git add file or wildcard
```

commit changed files

```
git commit -m 'comments'
```

view changes that are just committed

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
git diff origin/master..HEAD
```

push the new branch to repo / update the branch

```
git push origin 'new-branch'
```

revert changes in a file

```
git checkout file
```

see changes that are about to be pushed

```
git diff local_branch origin/master
```

delete local branch

```
git branch -d the_local_branch
```

Comment: One thing I've been confused about is, the GitHub UI has a great set of functions, and many of your commands can be done in the client,  is there any specific reason to still use git commands over just using the UI?

Comment: I think it is just about preference. I prefer using command. I also use EGit sometime, which is a UI plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: What would be the most straightforward way to update a duplicate to the upstream repo? Everyone keeps throwing tons of information at me but I just first just want to know this single thing.

Comment: Are you trying to clone a public repo and upload it as your private ?

Comment: Yes, but the cloning and uploading can be done completely without git commands. I imported a repo as my private repo, now all I want is be able to update it if the public repo gets updated.

Comment: There must be a better process of doing this, but you can do a 'git pull' on public repo, merge it with your local copy of private repo and push those changes to your remote repo.

Comment: Hey, I've been trying stuff for hours and I still just can't figure it out, is there a possibility you could tell me step by step what to do?