# How do I duplicate a Git repository including submodules?

Tags: git, github

I want to duplicate a repository, that also has a submodle - which is it's own repository.

When I duplicate the top-level repository (using the method described in [GitHub's help pages](//help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/)), only the top repository is duplicated, and the submodule is still linked to the original repository.

However, I want to (temporarily) make both repositories private and thus be able to edit both as full duplicates.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to create a fork of both the repo and any Sub modules into a private repo.  Then you would just remove the submodule from the original repo, then add a new submodule from your fork.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191261/6763316)'s a link that covers how to fork a public repo into a new private repo.

and [HERE](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/)'s a great post on removing and updating submodules.

Comment: thanks - that helped, but I ended up doing it a bit different than what it's in the links - please see my answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the same problem, here's what I did:

- duplicate the top repo in GitHub with their web form (https://github.com/new/import)
- duplicate the submodule in GitHub with the same form
- in the top repo: open the .gitmodules file and replace the submodule reference
- git add .gitmodules
- git commit & git-push

Worked like a charm.