# List previously private repository as being a fork

Tags: github, git-fork

I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065526/github-how-to-make-a-fork-of-public-repository-private) to fork a public repository into my private one. Now I want to list it as public, but it doesn't display as being a fork of that original repository.

How can I make a (previously private) fork be listed as a fork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, considering your private repo was not a fork in the first place.

What you can do is:

- create an actual (public fork)
- push your new commits from your private repo local clone to your new public fork, restoring your work in that public fork.