# How to Install a Private Package in NixOS

Tags: package, command, nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I compiled a package from my private git repository in NixOS. How can I install that package on a NixOS machine? I want to install my package and keep it private. Is there a command to install a private package in NixOS?

Constraint: I don't want to make my package publicly available on Nixpkgs.

Comment: Would you accept an answer that involves editing your `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file, and puts the package on the PATH for all users on the machine?

Comment: I'm not experienced with Nix. However, most package managers have some way to specify package sources. I suspect that NixOS is not confined to just the Nixpkgs repository. I bet the package sources can be configured in a NixOS configuration file. I suspect there would be a command to edit these package sources, too.

Comment: This is kind of a hack, but you could make a "private fork" of the nixpkgs repository (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065526/github-how-to-make-a-fork-of-public-repository-private) and possibly use that as a replacement to Nixpkgs. I'm just throwing that out as an idea. I suspect it could be a tedious solution.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, you can use all the build tools available inside nixpkgs in your private `configuration.nix`. One easy way is to

1. find a suitably similar build script within nixpkgs,
2. put it in the relevant list of packages (`environment.systemPackages`, `users.users.<username>.packages`, or some `services.<name>.package`) like any other package,
3. verify that everything is wired correctly by checking that the new configuration builds,
4. change the build script to refer to your package instead, then
5. rebuild the system.

For example, in case of a Python package the entry in the package list would look something like this:

```hs
(pkgs.python3Packages.buildPythonPackage rec {
    pname = "my-package";
    version = "1.2.3";
    src = ./my-package;
  }
)
```

(As an aside, usually nixpkgs builds are from source, not simply copying an already built package. I'd recommend that, to make it easier to port your package to future versions of nixpkgs without manually recompiling.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to build your nix package like so...

```bash
nix-build default.nix
```

...then you can easily install it using the `nix-env` command.

```bash
nix-env --install --file default.nix
```

That should install your package based on your nix expression file (`default.nix` in the example I gave).

Your package will NOT be added to Nixpkgs. Your package will NOT be publicly available, unless you are serving packages from your local nix store (which I doubt is the case).

I hope this helps :)