# How to merge from private mirror to public remote?

Tags: git

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30352360/384674), how can we create a pull request back in public remote?

Additionally, I do not really see a difference copying everything from my private branch to the public branch as the prerequisite is, that I can push to public repo...

Can someone explain?

My motivation for a private repo is, that I want to "fork" some project and maintain my configuration files privately. Can I do better? At the moment it is kind of maintaining two repositories separately.

**edit:** Thanks for another link. The concepts are similar - the one (I linked) required push privileges to public one, while second is addressing that need by public repo in the middle of other public (for which I possibly have no push privileges) and my private repo.

One question still remains: How to perform private repo to public repo push?

When I tried

```
git pull private_repo_yourname master
git push origin pull_request_yourname
```

from the first link, I got "Everything up-to-date" after the `git push`...

`git status` resulted in: "nothing to commit, working tree clean", but nothing went to the public repo...

Comment: To create a pull request : do like you said, just push to the public remote and open a pull request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub pull request from private to public repo possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834755/github-pull-request-from-private-to-public-repo-possible)

Comment: > "the prerequisite is, that I can push to public repo"..

I originally came up with this, in the original answer. But looks like we can do this without having push access to the public repo. The link from GoodDeeds above seems useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8834984/90998

Comment: Regarding "Everything up-to-date" - I'm not sure what's going on. One idea: Check that you've set up 'origin' correctly.

Comment: @Betlista I posted a detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834755/github-pull-request-from-private-to-public-repo-possible?noredirect=1&lq=1